# MPI_TYPE_CONTIGUOUS doesn't work correctly with custom type that contains a real(8)

Tags: fortran, mpi, fortran90, openmpi

I have a weird problem with defining a mpi_type_contiguous and using mpi_gatherv later on.
The type is defined as:

```
type glist
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!uncomment line below for int version:
!  integer :: iref , biref
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    real(8) :: rvar
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!uncomment line below for buggy version:
    integer :: ciref
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
end type glist
```

The code as it is now doesn't work. If I would comment `integer :: ciref` it would work. The same is true if I comment `real(8) :: rvar` instead and uncomment the two other integers `integer :: iref, biref`.

That means that the mistake depends both on the size of the datatype but only if there is a `real(8)` in there. If I have one `real(8)` and two `int` then it works again.

The code is designed to run with 3 threads(!). I was running it with openmpi and gfortran (mpif90). No special compile flags and execution with `mpirun -np 3 filename`. If somebody could run it with mpich or compile it with ifort or whatever that would be interesting so as to find out where the problem is coming from.

--- EDIT ---

Platinummonkey suggested below to use `mpi_type_struct` but it still doesn't work. If I do a `sizeof(glist)` with glist as above, I get 16 as an answer instead of 12.

--- /EDIT ---

Thanks in advance for your help.

The full code is (don't worry some of it can be ignored)

```
module mod_glist
type glist
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!uncomment line below for int version:
!  integer :: iref , biref
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    real(8) :: rvar
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!uncomment line below for buggy version:
    integer :: ciref
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
end type glist

contains

subroutine sof_glist(sof)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(out) :: sof

    type(glist) :: dum
    integer     :: val

    val = 0
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!uncomment line below for int version:
!  val = kind(dum%iref) + kind(dum%biref)
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    val = val + kind(dum%rvar)
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!uncomment line below for buggy version:
    val = val + kind(dum%ciref)
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    sof = val/kind(0)
    write(*,*) 'Size in bytes, integers: ', sof, val
end subroutine

end module mod_glist

program test_mpi_gatherv

use mpi
use mod_glist

    implicit none

    integer                                :: err, np, tp, nglout, i, j, nglin, sofgl, mpi_type_glist
    type(glist), dimension(:), allocatable :: gl, glcom, glsave
    integer    , dimension(:), allocatable :: glsize, nglinv, nglinp
    integer(kind=mpi_address_kind) :: ii, ij

    call mpi_init(err)
    call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, np, err)
    call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, tp, err)
    tp = tp + 1

    call sof_glist(sofgl)
    call mpi_type_contiguous(sofgl, mpi_integer, mpi_type_glist, err)
    call mpi_type_commit(mpi_type_glist, err)
    call mpi_type_get_extent(mpi_type_glist, ii, ij, err)
    write(*,*) 'extend: ', ii, ij

    allocate(glsize(np), nglinv(np), nglinp(np))

    glsize(1) = 5
    glsize(2) = 4
    glsize(3) = 3
    glsize(4:np) = 0

    allocate(gl(glsize(tp)))
    j = 1
    do i = 1,tp-1
      j = j+glsize(i)
    enddo

    do i = 1,glsize(tp)
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!uncomment line below for int version:
!    gl(i)%iref = j
!    gl(i)%biref = -j
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      gl(i)%rvar = real(j,8)
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!uncomment line below for buggy version:
      gl(i)%ciref = -j*10
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      j = j+1
    enddo

    do i=1,np ! setting up stuff can be ignored
      if(i.eq.1)then
        if(tp.eq.i)then
          nglinv(1) = 0
          nglinv(2) = 2
          nglinv(3) = 3
          nglinp(1) = 0
          nglinp(2) = nglinv(1) + nglinp(1)
          nglinp(3) = nglinv(2) + nglinp(2)
          nglin = nglinv(1) + nglinv(2) + nglinv(3)
          allocate(glcom(nglin))
          nglout = 0
        else
          if(tp.eq.2)then
            nglout = 2
            allocate(glcom(nglout))
            glcom(1) = gl(1)
            glcom(2) = gl(3)
          elseif(tp.eq.3)then
            nglout = 3
            allocate(glcom(nglout))
            glcom(1) = gl(1)
            glcom(2) = gl(2)
            glcom(3) = gl(3)
          endif
        endif
      elseif(i.eq.2)then
        if(tp.eq.i)then
          nglinv(1) = 3
          nglinv(2) = 0
          nglinv(3) = 2
          nglinp(1) = 0
          nglinp(2) = nglinv(1) + nglinp(1)
          nglinp(3) = nglinv(2) + nglinp(2)
          nglin = nglinv(1) + nglinv(2) + nglinv(3)
          allocate(glcom(nglin))
          nglout = 0
        else
          if(tp.eq.1)then
            nglout = 3
            allocate(glcom(nglout))
            glcom(1) = gl(2)
            glcom(2) = gl(4)
            glcom(3) = gl(5)
          elseif(tp.eq.3)then
            nglout = 2
            allocate(glcom(nglout))
            glcom(1) = gl(2)
            glcom(2) = gl(3)
          endif
        endif
      elseif(i.eq.3)then
        if(tp.eq.i)then
          nglinv(1) = 0
          nglinv(2) = 2
          nglinv(3) = 0
          nglinp(1) = 0
          nglinp(2) = nglinv(1) + nglinp(1)
          nglinp(3) = nglinv(2) + nglinp(2)
          nglin = nglinv(1) + nglinv(2) + nglinv(3)
          allocate(glcom(nglin))
          nglout = 0
        else
          if(tp.eq.1)then
            nglout = 0
            allocate(glcom(nglout))
          elseif(tp.eq.2)then
            nglout = 2
            allocate(glcom(nglout))
            glcom(1) = gl(1)
            glcom(2) = gl(4)
          endif
        endif
      endif ! end of setting up stuff

      if(i.eq.tp) allocate(glsave(nglin))

      ! debug output
      call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world, err)
      write(*,*) i, tp, nglout, nglin
      call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world, err)
      if(i.eq.tp) write(*,*) i, nglinv, nglinp
      call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world, err)
      ! end debug output

      call mpi_gatherv(glcom, nglout, mpi_type_glist, glsave, nglinv, nglinp, mpi_type_glist, i-1, mpi_comm_world, err)

      if(allocated(glcom)) deallocate(glcom)
    enddo

    ! debug output
    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world, err)
    do i = 1,nglin
      write(*,*) tp, i, glsave(i)
    enddo
    ! end debug output

    call mpi_finalize(err)

end program
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic error is that you cannot calculate the size of a derived type by summing the size of its components, because that ignores the padding which is necessary to satisfy alignment requirements. In your example, a real(8) needs to be aligned on a 8 byte boundary, so if the derived type contains a default kind integer (size 4 bytes), then the compiler will add 4 bytes of padding to ensure that the next element in the array of derived types will start on an 8 byte boundary. As pointed out in the answer by platinummonkey, the correct solution to this problem is to define an mpi_type_struct: [MPI struct datatype with an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231937/mpi-struct-datatype-with-an-array)

Also, assuming that the kind numbers are equivalent to the size of a type is not portable, it just happens to work in gfortran.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I just found the kind issue on another site.
I also found: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showpost.php?p=137806
which points out that the sizeof(glist) is divisible by the largest element. So this is were all my problems come from. So either I need to get rid of one variable or add another one, causing unnecessary overhead. I think I can get rid of the bool as the real(8) in my specific case is always larger than 0.

Answer (score 2):

See my old post about building your own struct. Much more reliable and will fit any combination of types.

[MPI struct datatype with an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231937/mpi-struct-datatype-with-an-array)

Comment: Ah cheers. I read your link in the other post. So contiguous only works with data of the same type. Good to know.

Comment: Actually it's still not working. I will investigate it in detail later. For now all I can tell you is that `sizeof(glist)` returns 24 (containing 1 bool, 2 int, 1 real(8) = 20 bytes). Which is 4 byte too much. If I add another int (so that the type actually has 24 bytes) it works with `mpi_type_struct` (but also with contiguous).

Comment: Please see the comment to the other answer, especially the link I provided.